# Check whether point coordinate lies within polygon

Tags: r, r-sf

I'm new to spatial data and need some help. I have a set of 1million points and would like to identify which of those are located within one of 5 polygons. Once identified, I would like to delete the entire row of that point.

The polygons are found within a kml file and the points in a csv. After reading the data, I did the following:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

#create sf of lat long
heat_df$point <- heat_df[,5:6] %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c(1,2)) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326)

#make planar
heat_df$point <- st_transform(heat_df$point, 2163)
kml$geometry <- st_transform(kml$geometry, 2163)

#iterate over the following 5 times (once per polygon)
heat_df$inter <- st_intersects(heat_df$point, kml$geometry[1], sparse = FALSE)
heat_df <-  heat_df[!(heat_df$inter == TRUE),]
```

However, I couldn't find any points in those polygons, even though I know that there are points in those polygons. I checked the data frames and noticed that the coordinates are apparently formatted differently:

```
> print(heat_df$point[1])
[[1]]
[1] 6407800 9211903
attr(,"class")
[1] "XY"    "POINT" "sfg"  

> print(kml$geometry[1])
[[1]]
[[1]]
         [,1]    [,2] [,3]
 [1,] 4520903 5043254    0
 [2,] 4520945 5043244    0
 [3,] 4521016 5043207    0
 [4,] 4521029 5043312    0
 [5,] 4521027 5043325    0
 [6,] 4521016 5043341    0
 [7,] 4520962 5043405    0
 [8,] 4520926 5043388    0
 [9,] 4520903 5043254    0

attr(,"class")
[1] "XYZ"     "POLYGON" "sfg"
```

At least the coordinates in `heat_df$point[1]` are very different from the ones in `kml$geometry[1]`. All points and all polygons are located within 1km of each other. So I don't expect point coordinates like `[1] 6407800 9211903` and polygon coordinates like `[1,] 4520903 5043254    0`. But maybe I'm wrong. I haven't worked with spatial data before. Can you help me figure out what's wrong? I want to stick to the `sf` package, if possible.

Comment: To help you properly, we would need to see your data which you did not include. To find out whether points lie in polygons, you can use the `sp::over()` or the sf equivalent listed here: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/wiki/migrating

Comment: It also appears that your polygon is a flattened 3d shape. You could remove the third dimension (z or [,3])

Comment: Hi Mikko, thank you for your help. It works now (see my comment to Jindra Lacko). Also, thanks for pointing out that I had an elevation dimension in my polygons. I removed them with `st_zm()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class of problems you describe is called point in polygon.

You can handle it via `sf::st_join()` - it will add polygon columns to your point dataset. It uses left join as default = preserves rows of left hand object. It is therefore the best to start with your points object, and add to that characteristics of your polygons when spatially aligned (and NAs when not).

Two things to keep in mind:

- the CRS system has to be aligned (which one you choose matters rarely; it would take an extreme edge case - but it has to be aligned; use `st_transform` for that)
- depending on the class of your points object (sfc vs. sf) you may need to call `st_as_sf()` first

Consider something along these lines:

```
pip <- points %>%
  st_join(heat_df)
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! However, the issue wasn't my method. `st_intersect()` works too. The problem I had was that I combined two columns (lat and long) to one sfc object (point) column, mixing up lat and long. This caused the difference between my point and polygon coordinates I described above. In effect, points were located somewhere else and `st_intersect()`couldn't find any matches.

Comment: Ah... Happens to me all the time. I have learned to recognize the look of points in the middle of Arabian sea / which is the place where my usual area of interest ends up with flipped coords. A major facepalm ensues... Glad you managed to sort it out!